# SSLPeerUnverifiedException When starting the AWS Kinesis Webrtc stream for first time only

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

Greetings to the one who is reading this and thanks for the help and time you are about to spend.

I am working with AWS kinesis Web RTC and trying to stream live video from a camera device but when the app is installed for the first time it crashes while creating the Connection with the exception below. If again I restart the device or restart the app it works fine. Tried out some solutions, I came across on various online platforms but was still not able to figure it out.

The code line on which it is happening is below

CODE:

`val describeSignalingChannelResult = awsKinesisVideoClient?.describeSignalingChannel( DescribeSignalingChannelRequest() .withChannelName(channelName) )`

Exception:

```
EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
                                                                                                 Process: com.secure56.app, PID: 26211
                                                                                                 com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Hostname kinesisvideo.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com not verified:
                                                                                                     certificate: sha1/------------------
                                                                                                     DN: CN=kinesisvideo.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
                                                                                                     subjectAltNames: [kinesisvideo.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com]
                                                                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:456)
                                                                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:229)
                                                                                                    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AWSKinesisVideoClient.invoke(AWSKinesisVideoClient.java:2077)
                                                                                                    at com.amazonaws.services.kinesisvideo.AWSKinesisVideoClient.describeSignalingChannel(AWSKinesisVideoClient.java:930)
                                                                                                    at com.android56.app.onecam.kvs.SignallingDataCreator.updateSignallingChannelInfoTask(SignallingDataCreator.kt:158)
                                                                                                    at com.android56.app.onecam.kvs.SignallingDataCreator$updateSignallingChannelInfoTask$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
                                                                                                    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.LimitedDispatcher.run(LimitedDispatcher.kt:42)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.TaskImpl.run(Tasks.kt:95)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:570)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:677)
                                                                                                    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:664)
                                                                                                    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@fb144, Dispatchers.IO]
                                                                                                 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname kinesisvideo.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com not verified:
                                                                                                     certificate: sha1/z60CQXD0myU9Ol4CyrQpESqcV3Y=
                                                                                                     DN: CN=kinesisvideo.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com
                                                                                                     subjectAltNames: [kinesisvideo.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com]
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:1480)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:1415)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:1359)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:221)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:144)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:106)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:400)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:333)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:483)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:135)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:266)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:219)
                                                                                                    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.perf.network.InstrURLConnectionBase.getOutputStream(InstrURLConnectionBase.java:165)
                                                                                                    at com.google.firebase.perf.network.InstrHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(InstrHttpsURLConnection.java:89)
                                                                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.writeContentToConnection(UrlHttpClient.java:162)
                                                                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.UrlHttpClient.execute(UrlHttpClient.java:75)
                                                                                                    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:386)
```

I am following the steps from sample app on github

Some details

`def aws_version = '2.68.0' implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-kinesisvideo:$aws_version@aar") { transitive = true } implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-kinesisvideo-signaling:$aws_version@aar") { transitive = true } implementation("com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-kinesisvideo-webrtcstorage:$aws_version@aar") { transitive = true } implementation('org.glassfish.tyrus.bundles:tyrus-standalone-client:1.20') { exclude module: 'javax.inject' } implementation 'org.awaitility:awaitility:3.0.0'`